# datatables sorting with images

Tags: sorting, datatables

I have the following problem - I have a datatable with n number of rows. The first column is Serial Number using simple counter. My table has a functionality in which when I double click the row, it becomes editable and 'check' and 'cancel' images show up in the first column, right beside the serial number. User can edit row and save/cancel the row accordingly.
The problem with this logic is, since there are images in the first column, I'm not able to sort the table based on the first column. When I remove the images, sorting works perfectly.

I know this is a weird problem, but I really dont want to change the editing logic for this.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got help from datatables.net. Removed the images from the first column. On edit event, used jQuery `append` and `remove` to add/remove the elements to the first column.